# PayPal PDT is not returning a tx value in the QueryString when using custom return URL

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is a follow up question to [PayPal PDT is not Returning a tx value in the Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585003/paypal-pdt-is-not-returning-a-tx-value-in-the-query-string)

I am struggeling with the same problem, but also using the real PayPal and not the sandbox:
As soon as I specify a custom return URL in my PayPal Form the tx parameter is not attached anymore.

**Is there still a way to solve this problem?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the payment? You need to give us something to test with, e.g. a button or cart upload form post.  It's next to impossible for us to figure out what's wrong without any context to reproduce the issue.

Even though there is a return there may not *be* a tx for this checkout, for instance if it's a future subscription payment.  So in that case tx would be empty.

On a general note, you shouldn't be using PDT for anything important.  Even though a given transaction is successful the PDT return may never occur for whatever reason. Most simply, if the customer doesn't choose to return or their browser crashes beforehand.

So, don't use PDT.  Use IPN for any important business logic.  (or if you're able to program the checkout, there are far better options such as the Express Checkout API with SolutionType=Sole)

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the problem and as I am using IPN anyway (which works fine) I will mark this anser as correct...

Comment: This is not an answer. Downvoting.

Comment: There wasn't much of a question in any case, but the important thing is to not use PDT for anything important whatsoever. It is for informational purposes only and its complete absence should never be an issue any system is unequipped to handle.